# QT QML Photo Gallery symbian^1

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator, qml, photo-gallery

I try to open a widows on image folder with library MGFetch,

i've no probleme in symbian^3, but on symbian^1 when i include :

```
  #include <MGFetch.h>
```

i've this error during building :

```
No rule to make target `\QtSDK\Symbian\SDKs\Symbian1Qt473\epoc32\release\armv5\LIB\mgfetch.dso', needed by `\QtSDK\Symbian\SDKs\Symbian1Qt473\epoc32\release\gcce\udeb\fichierSym1_Essai2.exe'.  Stop.
```

is it possible to use MGFetch on symbian^1 ?

i create a new project just with this line,and it's not working.
i add this line on pro file :

```
symbian:LIBS += -lmgfetch -lbafl
```

if it's not possible to use it on symbian^1 what else can i use to have a image gallery ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added bafl.lib? Here's a page with a few other options: http://www.symlab.org/wiki/index.php/Apps:How_to_fetch_multimedia_files

Comment: Yes, same probleme when i add lbafl. i add this on post. i've try using Using CAknFileSelectionDialog, but i've a error too : "undefined reference to `PathInfo::PhoneMemoryRootPath()'".i did not try last option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problems with the servicehandler lib. I could copy the files from the Symbian^3 SDK to Symbian^1 and it just worked. No guarantee for your libs of course.

Comment: i've try to copy file to Symbian1Qt473\epoc32\release\armv5\lib\ServiceHandler.lib (+dso...), but i still have the same error, is it the good way to copy libs ? thanks

Comment: ...i needed to copy mgfetch lib ;) thanks !
Symbian1Qt473\epoc32\release\armv5\lib\mgfetch.dso (+lib)